# Toggle holding 2 keys at the same time - slow speed

Tags: toggle, autohotkey, delay

I am using Autohotkey to hold down 2 keys at the same time, when doing it by hand it is much faster then my code. Did I make a mistake?

[If it was unclear what I ment, I recorded it in a short clip, first one is by hand, second with the script](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93EIwTgEKyg)

```
F7::
SetKeyDelay, 0
Toggle := !Toggle
If (Toggle)
    Send {1 down}{2 down}
Else
    Send {1 up}{2 up}
Return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#maxThreadsPerHotkey, 2
setKeyDelay, 50, 50
setMouseDelay, 50
banana:=0

$F7::
banana:=!banana
    while (banana=1)
    {
        send, {1}{2}
        sleep, 100
    }
Return

esc::ExitApp
```

From this tread:

[Autofire and togle](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=11952)

Comment: Perfect, I only had to edit "sleep" to match my keyboard repeat delay and got exactly what I needed, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do. This script seems to press and hold down 1 and 2, until you press F7 again and both keys are released again. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: That is what I want it to do, the issue is, it's doing it way slower then when I do it manually and I have no idea why. The video shows this very clearly.

Comment: Not sure what the video was trying to show. When you say "doing it manually" does that really mean manually, or with a script with two triggers (e.g. F7 and F8)?

Comment: Yes, I was holding down the two buttons with my fingers.
I am just confused why that would have a different outcome (different speed) then when the script does it and was hoping there is a fix.